# How to produce a line break with the runin style?

Tags: line-breaking, titlesec

When using the `runin` style for sections, text will immediately follow the title. However, in some rare situation I would like to have a line break after the title. How should I achieve this?

I tried to add `\par` or `\leavevmode`, but they don't work here.

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{Title}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a combination of `\leavevmode` and `\par`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{Title}
\leavevmode\par\noindent Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to do it. Anyway, here's the answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Title}\mbox{}\\*
Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\mbox{}` triggers the typesetting of the title; with `\\*` you go to a new line with no possible page break in between.

If you need a `\label` (not with `\section*`, of course), it has to go either in the argument to `\section` or before `\mbox{}`.